what wounds would a plasma weapon actually create?
Plasma is a quite common weapon in sci-fi, despite the realistic problems this has when weaponizing it.
Now pretty much all media showcases plasma weapons as being cauterizing weapons. But plasma weapons tend to not just be hot, but need to be compressed in order to deliver enough energy to the target upon impact. So the gas would expand upon contact and also need to be powerful enough to flash-vaporize the surface of the target or it will not be damaging enough to take over kinetic weapons. Flash-vaporization is essentially an explosion, and explosions tend to not cauterize but deal damage mostly with the shockwaves (and shrapnel).
An example of how this might function can be found here under blasters: https://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/sidearmenergy.php
But it's hard to find solid data about this. So my question is, how would a typical sci-fi plasma bolt actually function?
This means that like sci-fi, we disregard things like how the bolt stays together or how damaging the magnetic field necessary to keep it together would be. Only the plasma itself is considered here!

Are you making the mistake of believing the technobabble rationalization for a "blaster" is real? Plasma damage during integrated circuit manufacturing is a well understood problem. I suspect what you really mean is, "if we embrace the madness and assume the existence of a hand-held pistol that can emit a thin and well-contained corridor of plasma over an arbitrary distance without consideration for energy, heat loss or plasma source limitations, what damage would that plasma really cause to an unprotected human body?" And since that's fictional, I wouldn't expect any hard data to exist.

Which was all a long-winded way of saying that you must (a) define exactly one target for the plasma bolt, (b) define what material will be used to create the plasma, (c) define the geometry of the impact (simplistically, the diameter of the plasma corridor, (d) must define or reject what losses will occur while the plasma moves down the corridor. Once we know all that, we can ascertain what kind of damage would occur.

I'm tempted to ask you to consider using hydrogen as your plasma source. No non-solid containment (e.g., magnetic) is perfectly impermeable. The inevitable leakage of some hydrogen plasma into an oxygenated atmosphere, if I remember my chemistry correctly, will cause an explosion. Because the leakage is small, it might manifest as an atmosphere-burning beam. That would be cool.

@JBH I am making the mistake of assuming you would look into the source or that you'd accept the premise of the question. The point of Atomic Rockets is to give reasonable scientific answers to science fiction. Such as how stealth in space would or would not be possible, how to make a laser weapon work in different conditions (blaster being defined as a pulsed laser and not a plasma weapon like you say here). If you want to degrade my questions and sources I expect you to at least attempt to read them first.

Strictly speaking, I think @JBH denigrated the question, rather than degrading it.

They will resemble industrial strength electrical burns
High voltage electrical currents can almost instantly raise the temperature of flesh up to thousands of degrees which will cause about the same damage profile you would expect from a plasma based weapon.  In fact, plasma cutters are a metal working tool that function specifically by rapidly heating steel with such an electrical current; so, a plasma gun is basically just the same thing, but at a distance.
I could post a picture, but honestly those things can be horribly gruesome, and I don't want to get my account blocked for inappropriate content.  The injuries can be so bad that they would almost instantly become a war crime given how modern nations feel about cruel and disfiguring weapons. If you really want to know what they look like, you could turn off Google Safe Search, go to images, and look it up... but don't just don't...  However, since I've already made that mistake myself, I will instead just describe it so that you do not have to see it.

 Where the plasma bolt hits, the skin will char and shrink causing it to rip open and pull the underlying muscles and tendons appart.  The flesh underneath will tear along the fascial planes between the affected Muscle groups as the underlying muscles will boil off causing them to rapidly cook, dry, and shrink. There will be significant amounts of black charred flesh, but it will not be the entire contiguous wound.  Instead you will see a lot of black flesh around the perimeter of the wound and on the surface of the muscle groups but there will also be some mostly raw chasms of flesh visible where the fascial planes are torn open by the rapid shrinkage.  If you've ever had a black-and-blue lamb loin steak, it looks kind of like that.

 Depending on where the weapon hits, you will likely see any tendons, aponeurosises, bones, etc. continuing to hold the mangled flesh together and showing through the wound in whitish bands. It is unlikely that the wound would significantly bleed unless there is a major artery that is too well protected to burn shut but not well enough protected to keep it from ripping.  In which case, you may see a mostly dry looking wound that bleeds heavily from just one or two places.

Personally, I'd recommend just saying it's a big charred hole, especially if you are doing anything with a visual medium like TV or a Videogame, because the reality of what such a wound looks like is more awful than most audiences will be okay with.

Could you show that the difference between an extremely short time the plasma can work (tiny explosion) compared to a longer time electricly formed plasma would truly be different? It seems to me like the difference between a flamethrower and an explosion. One has more time to cause the damage and function meaning the other has a higher amount of energy released in a shorter time.

@Demigan the effects I'm explaining are from"explosive" electrocution.  Long duration, lower intensity electrocution is unlikely to break the skin, but can cause a lot of muscular and neurological internal damage, and minor burning at the contact point, and high intensity electrocution that is too fast to cause an explosive effect can cause Lichtenberg figures.

What you’re looking for isn’t real.

So my question is, how would a typical sci-fi plasma bolt actually function?


This means that like sci-fi, we disregard things like how the bolt stays together or how damaging the magnetic field necessary to keep it together would be. Only the plasma itself is considered here!

You might be attacking this from the wrong angle. If your sci-fi is hard enough that you care about what kind of injuries a plasma bolt would actually cause, you should also be worried about how you’re producing/containing/projecting the plasma. I think JBH summed it up really well in comments:

Are you making the mistake of believing the technobabble rationalization for a "blaster" is real?

A “blaster” or “phaser” or whatever is invariably just a projectile weapon that causes whatever damage needs to be done for the plot, sometimes with different power levels/sizes built in so it makes a bit more sense. See also: in Star Wars and related cinema/literature, where the majority of ranged weapons in most areas are “blasters”, regular people (plot-important characters) routinely survive shots to the torso with minimal armor, while soldiers (plot-unimportant characters or people who have to die for Plot Reasons) die instantly when shot anywhere even through heavy armor. See also Star Trek captains surviving abuse that would make a normal human die of shock while they can hit an armored soldier in the shoulder with a “phaser” and get a one-hit kill.
The point here is that blasters aren’t a real thing, they’re a stand-in for “whatever projectile weapon is convenient to forward the plot in a world-consistent way”.
That’s not fun, though.
I propose another answer, though. We call them “plasma blasters” not because the projectiles are plasma but because the projectiles create plasma. This has many different benefits:

You can have either unlimited or limited ammo, depending on choice.

If you want unlimited ammo, then the projectile is a tiny stream of moisture collected from the atmosphere/a small onboard tank, plus a tiny-but-heavily-charged mote of dust on the leading edge. When the dust hits the target, the moisture creates a route for a massive amount of electrical charge to move from a capacitor plate on the gun to the dust, ionizing the surrounding air in transit and delivering a substantial amount of energy to the target. Depending on the gun’s charge capacity, the damage can be superficial burns or complete disintegration.

If you want limited ammo, then the projectile is a chemically-propelled pellet containing a tiny loop of (metastable metallic hydrogen)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen] or similarly-exotic phlebotinum, which as a superconductor can store a very large current without issue. When the pellet breaks apart on impact, the energy stored in the electrical current flowing in a loop through the superconductor is released in the form of radiation that ionizes the air around the impact site. Depending on the size of the pellet/its stored current, the damage dealt can, again, be just a burn or complete annihilation. (Metallic hydrogen also burns exceptionally-hot, if that’s a factor.)



You don’t need to explain how the plasma is generated…

…because you just did. The plasma is generated by the weapon’s projectile, not the weapon itself.
No plasma must be stored, and it doesn’t need to be projected in a particular direction; no complex magnetic fields/lasers/etc that inevitably become much more complicated/expensive than a kinetic weapon of equivalent quality.


You’re still dealing damage with plasma, and in any case the resultant effect looks physics-y enough that people will buy it as some sort of high-energy weapon instead of an overbaked kinetic weapon, so calling it a “plasma gun” is still perfectly-reasonable from both the Watsonian and Doylist perspectives.



As far as direct injury goes, plasma is hot gas. Imagine a welding torch on a 50 meter pole (balanced on a fulcrum near the middle, of course). That's your plasma gun, except space magic gets the hot gas to the target 50m away instead of a long stick. Looking at it unprotected will injure your vision. It'll burn you badly if it stays on target for a second, but it probably won't, so you just get superficial burns. Not a great weapon.
We can space magic harder to change the effects. Explosions are also hot gas, so if you pretty much any kind of exploding projectile could be some combination of space magic, some plasma, and maybe some other material (like if you want a liquid metal jet propelled by an explosion, you'll want your space magic to carry some metal along with the plasma). But at this point the space magic is definitely doing all the work; the plasma is just there to let us call it a plasma gun.

**
Plasma can be accelerated to high velocities
** And since the atoms that make up the plasma have mass that means a burst of condensed plasma can hypothetically have a high impact velocity as well as a high temperature. For example one proposed plasma weapon was a dual pulse laser beam. The first pulse strikes the target and vaporizes (plasmaizes) a small section of the targets surface. Almost instantaneously after that a second pulse  (tuned to the optimal frequency) strikes the small ball of plasma before it can disburse. At least part of the plasma is then instantly accelerated back into the target at a small % of the speed of light by the powerful laser beam behind it!
The result would theoretically be some structural damage to the target. I don't have the math to calculate how much.

To answer what kind of woulds plasma weapons would cause, we need to look at what plasma is. Plasma is the fourth state of matter, the molecules being so energized that they release that energy as intense light and heat. Plasma most naturally appears in stars, but we as humans on earth more commonly see it in light bulbs and florescent lights. As you pointed out, the plasma does have mass, and to be fired out would need to have a certain amount of pressure, meaning the hot energized matter would hit you at fast speeds.
If you were hit by a blast from a plasma rifle, you would first be hit by the impact of the high speed projectile, which would likely throw you back and damage your internal organs, if not just punch a hold right through your body. Second, the heat from the plasma would in fact burn whatever part of the body it hits. If the blast does in fact punch through the target, this might actually prevent bleeding through cauterization, though this may not help you live if a vital organ is damaged. The extreme heat from the plasma could instantly vaporize your blood, causing parts of your body to pop and burst from the pressure of the evaporated fluid. All together, a plasma rifle might be one of deadliest weapons (that only attack one person at a time) in fiction.
Just for fun, let's also look at what might protect you from a plasma rifle. The main factors we have to consider are A; the impact, and B; the heat. The only thing I know of to protect a human from impact force are bomb suits made from layers of high and low density foam to absorb and dissipate the shockwave from bomb explosions. Something similar would need to be applied here. As for the heat, I looked at what firefighters use to protect from heat, and I got FR-underclothing, a fire-resistant protective layer that also manages moisture levels, which will hopefully help with the heat from the plasma, though I can't ensure that as plasma is really, really hot. Like, 11,000 to 14,500 degrees Fahrenheit as opposed to fire being 2,012 to 2,192 degrees fahrenheit. So you know what, forget it, you'd need a sci-fi super armor to survive a plasma blast.

If the plasma creates pops and bursts, would this not tear the (brittle) cauterized section apart and leave room for bleeding?

I didn't think of that, you have a point. Just emphasizes how ridiculously deadly a plasma rifle would be.
